# Azure Cosmos settings history

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to review the history of changes to the setting of an Azure Cosmos database. I believe I am colliding with another them who is using the same Cosmos database. I would like to review all the setting that have changed since the database was created. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [audit control plane operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/audit-control-plane-logs) for any Cosmos DB resource once it has been created. However, the account must be configured such that all control plane operations are done against the Cosmos DB resource provider and not through one of the data plane SDKs. See the link for details on this.

However, ARM does not support providing information on when a resource was created. This is a limitation of ARM, not Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna watch who did operations on your cosmos database, I think 'Activity Log' tab could help you. It records some message like screenshot below.

But I found that I can't get the details of the operations such as changing RU. By the way, I didn't find any documents saying how to review operations in cosmosdb. Or maybe you can provide more details about what information you wanna get from cosmosdb?

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was asking more about setup information. For instance, I can't even find when the Database was created or who created it. Seems pretty basic need but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry for have not found any solution to your requests until now.